# Calcalate term frequency in MYSQL?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, frequency

STILL HAVING THIS PROBLEM!

I am having a table in SQL with 4 fields: FILEID, SENTENCEID, WORDID and WORD.

I arrange all the files with the given file number, under every file I give every sentence an unique number, under every sentence, I assign every word with a unique number, as shown in the picture.

I am trying to calculate the number of times a word shows in every document. I only know how to calculate how many times a term shows in this table in total. Can anyone suggest how to calculate based on FILEID? Many thanks. [Below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1sLi.jpg) is the table I have.

[image]

This is my current query:

```sql
SELECT WORD, COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT WORD FROM ASSIGNMENT2 GROUP BY FILEID);
```

Comment: This is hard to answer without seeing your database schema.  Also, what exactly do you mean by "term" and "document"?

Comment: This is a collection of multiple files. The FILEID in the picture represent different files. Term means words. In a sentence every word has a unique ID from 1, 2, 3, 4,... Once the sentence ends, I reassign 1, 2, 3, ... to words in a new sentence.

Comment: OK. So am I correct in my understanding that you're trying to find out how many times a particular word appears in a particular file?

Comment: No, I am trying to come up with a list of all words, with the information of word | FILEID | FREQUENCY(how many times it shows up in this one file).

Answer (score 1):

I'd say:

```
select FILEID, WORD, count(WORD) from ASSIGNMENT2 group by FILEID, WORD
```